# MYSQL how to select data from two lists where there is no matching data?

Tags: mysql

I have two tables that contain the following fields:

1) ID
2) Email

Table one and Table two have the same data however, Table two has less. I would like to create a new table where i select all the records from both tables where there is no matching email addresses. How would i do this?

Comment: Can you provide a better explanation of the tables involved (i.e. their structure, sample data, etc.) and sample result set that you would be looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply `UNION` two table, there will no 2 row with same data

for example if you have to table

```
[table X]
    ID  Email       
------  --------
     1  x       
     2  y       
     3  z       
     4  t   

[table Y]
    ID  Email       
------  --------
     1  x       
     6  g       
     2  v
```

query

```
SELECT ID,Email FROM X UNION SELECT ID,Email FROM Y
```

or

```
SELECT ID,Email FROM (SELECT ID,Email FROM X UNION SELECT ID,Email FROM Y) t
```

will give result

```
    ID  Email       
------  --------
     1  x       
     2  y       
     3  z       
     4  t       
     6  g       
     2  v
```

Comment: This works but i have another question. Basically i am sending out a html email and i have a list of addresses in table 1. I have been sent an updated list which have less addresses because a few people have unsubscribed and i have put all of that into another table two. I don't know exactly who has unsubscribed but following your method, how would i know that the data pulled out from the query is correct if that makes any sense?

Comment: Sorry but I don't get what you want. You want query all unsubscribe email which in long-list but not in the short-list ?

Answer (score 1):

Considering `table1` is joined to `table2` on column `col1`

Try this :::

```
Select 
col1, col2
from table1
left join table2 on (table1.col1 = table2.col1)
where table1.col2!=table2.col2 and table2.col1 is null

UNION 

Select 
col1, col2
from table2
left join table1 on (table1.col1 = table2.col1)
where table1.col2!=table2.col2 and table1.col1 is null
```